# Is every odd function on a symmetric interval of $\mathbb{R}$ lebesgue integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

For example is an odd $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ over the entire real line Lebesgue Integrable? I know that its improper Riemann integral will always exist and equal zero so I am asking if the same rule can be applied to Lebesgue integration?

Comment: The identity map is an odd function but is not Lebesgue integrable over the real line.

Comment: Signed indicator function on non-measurable set?

Comment: It is certainly not the case that its improper Riemann integral (or even Lebesgue integral) will always exist. For that, you need continuity conditions and such like.

Comment: If by Lebesgue integrable you mean $L^{1}$ (i.e. $\int |f| < \infty$), then I don't see why this would be the case -- $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ for $x > 0$ and $0$ for $x = 0$ and $-\frac{1}{x}$ for $x < 0$. This function is odd but certainly not $L^{1}$

Comment: Also, the Lebesgue integral $\int_{-1}^{1} f$ (for the $f$ above) is not even defined because the positive and negative parts each integrate to $\infty$